# C# maskedTextBox Sum Help

Tags: c#, winforms

Need help with getting sum from other masked textbox * .0628

```
   private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        maskedTextBox2.Text = (
            maskedTextBox1.Text *.0628 + //Cost of Rail
            200
            ).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Hey Russell. I saw your last post as well. I think you should really look at the error that you get when you try to compile and think about what it is trying to tell you. I expect here that you would have gotten a compiler error telling you that you can do the multiplication operation on the string. This would help you see that you need to cast the string to an appropriate type.

Comment: Sorry bout that I am so new to this I have been using Visual Basic my entire career up to this point.

Comment: No problem - just trying to help you out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
   private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        maskedTextBox2.Text = (
            (float.Parse(maskedTextBox1.Text) *.0628 + //Cost of Rail
            200)
            ).ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`maskedTextBox1.Text` is a string. You need to convert it to a numeric data type before you can do arithmetic on it. `Decimal` seems appropriate in this case. `float` or `double` may be appropriate as well. Make sure you understand the differences between all of them before picking one.

```
maskedTextBox2.Text = (
    Decimal.Parse(maskedTextBox1.Text) * 0.0628m + //Cost of Rail
    200
    ).ToString();
```

Note that you will probably want to do validation, etc. If the conversion fails, you will get an exception. You can test if the conversion works by using [`Decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx).

Comment: It is important to understand the differences.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       decimal sum2 = 0;
       decimal.TryParse(maskedTextBox2.Text, out sum2);
        maskedTextBox2.Text = (
            sum2 * 0.0628m +  200
            ).ToString();
    }
```

first of all
parse string from maskedTextBox2 as decimal
then use it to create new value

second
You can't write decimal numbers like 0.8888 you have to add m at the end so compiler can understand that entered value is decimal.